# zsh: segmentation fault when trying to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to plot a simple thing this error pops up:

> zsh: segmentation fault
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

The code I run is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5]) 
plt.show() 
plt.plot([2,2,2,2,2]) 
plt.show()
```

I have updated my Mac to Big Sur, so that's maybe it. VSC and Python are up to date.

How can I resolve the above problem?

Comment: Try https://colab.research.google.com/ if urgent.

Comment: create a virtual environment  or upgrade/reistall python. I think somehow your python link is wrong 

'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3' should be

'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python'

nothing wrong with your code. i think your path or python installation is corrupted . I am using Big Sur . python 3.9

Comment: code is OK. Problem is only your system.